# GUI applications and chroot

Tags: chroot

I have followed all of the instructions on this page to try and get a graphical program running from inside a chrooted environment

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

The only difference is that I substituted xenial for trusty.

The installation went fine and no complaints in the terminal at issuing any of the commands.

However, when I get to the part where is says I can run firefox in a chrooted environment with this command:

```
gksudo chroot /var/chroot firefox -DISPLAY=:0.0
```

the firefox window does not come up. A window comes up asking for my administrative password, which I enter, and then nothing, it just exits to a command prompt with no messages.

I'm hoping there is a simple answer to this, thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I installed firefox inside the chroot and it ran from inside the chroot. Then I ran the command from outside the chroot like in the article and it ran from outside the chroot. I think they may have omitted a step in the instructions.

Comment: Which step? It's implied that firefox is installed on the chrooted system. Otherwise it makes no sense!

Answer (score 1):

Change `-DISPLAY=:0.0` to `--display=:0.0`.

Comment: It works either way.